# create objects in ruby with our own custom method in ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I need to create an object with my own custom method in ruby instead of default new().

```
obj = User.new
```

If I need to create an object for a user with generate(), how this can be achieved.
So when I type

```
obj = User.generate
```

it should create an object of User.

One way I understand is by aliasing the method with alias keyword.

Though I am not sure.

Is there any suggestion for doing it.??

Comment: Why do you need this? I’m assuming there’s some specific reason why `new` doesn’t do what you want, otherwise just use `new`.

Answer (score 4):

As you say, you can just `alias_method` it:

```
 class << User
   alias_method :generate, :new
 end
```

You could also delegate:

```
class User
  def self.generate(*args, &blk)
    new(*args, &blk)
  end
end
```

Or, you could re-implement what `Class#new` does:

```
class User
  def self.generate(*args, &blk)
    obj = allocate
    obj.send(:initialize, *args, &blk)
    obj
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class User
  def self.generate
    new
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class method called `generate` inside your `User` class

Comment: Would this do: `class User; def self.generate; puts "How now, brown cow?"; end; end`?

Comment: Yes, just as others have posted below. But please, don't write it in one line

Comment: @CarySwoveland Not sure but I am hoping the first comment was a satirical jab at the answer unless I missed it in the docs I don't think `new` ever puts out `How now, brown cow?` :). @PiotrKruczek this isn't really and answer since the OP wanted to know how to create a `generate` method that acts like `new` which your answer does not cover.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your specific method and inside it call self.new

```
class User
  def self.generate
    self.new
  end
end

obj = User.generate
```